# Minimal graded free resolution and matrix representations

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

> In a graded $R$-module, let $$0 \to C_p \xrightarrow{\phi_p} C_{p-1} \xrightarrow{\phi_{p-1}}C_{p-2} \to \dots \to C_1 \xrightarrow{\phi_1} C_0 \xrightarrow{\psi} M \to 0$$ be a *minimal* graded free resolution. Why does every nonzero entry in the matrix map defining $\phi_i$ must be in $\left < x_1, \dots, x_n \right > \subset R$.

My reasoning is going to sound silly, but isn't this included from the definition of minimal? Recall

> **Definition:** A graded resolution is *minimal* if $\phi_i(F_i) \subset mF_{i - 1}$ with $m = \left< x_1,\dots, x_n\right >$ whenever $F_i = Rg_1 \oplus \dots \oplus Rg_t$. The map $\phi( \sum_{i = 1}^{t} f_ig_i \to \sum_{i = 1}^{t} f_im_i ) = \sum_{i = 1}^{r} a_ie_i$. 
>   So $\phi_i(F_1) \subset mF_{i - 1}$ means every $a_i \in (x_1, \dots, x_n).$

Comment: Could you explain me this relation: $\phi( \sum_{i = 1}^{t} f_ig_i \to \sum_{i = 1}^{t} f_im_i ) = \sum_{i = 1}^{r} a_ie_i$? I've never seen a function defined in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $f:F\to G$ be a linear map of finite free $R$-modules with $f(F)\subseteq\mathfrak mG$. Then the matrix associated to $f$ in *any* two bases has all entries in $\mathfrak m$.

Let $\{x_1,\dots,x_m\}\subset F$ and $\{y_1,\dots,y_n\}\subset G$ be two bases, and write $f(x_i)=\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}g_j$ with $a_{ij}\in R$. This way we associates to $f$ a matrix $A=(a_{ij})$.
Since $f(F)\subseteq\mathfrak mG$ we can also write $f(x_i)=\sum_{j=1}^km_{ij}g_j$ with $m_{ij}\in\mathfrak m$ and $g_j\in G$. (Here $g_j$ depends also on $i$, but this is no important for what follows.)
Now write $g_j=\sum_{r=1}^nb_{jr}y_r$, plug this into the previous equation and get $$f(x_i)=\sum_{j=1}^km_{ij}(\sum_{r=1}^nb_{jr}y_r),$$ so $$f(x_i)=\sum_{r=1}^n(\sum_{j=1}^km_{ij}b_{jr})y_r.$$ This gives us $a_{ij}=\sum_{j=1}^km_{ij}b_{jr}\in\mathfrak m$.

Comment: Thank you user26857. Your reparaphrased statement at the beginning in the yellow box is very helpful for me to understand.